# How to find subset with same number of intersection?

Tags: algorithm

I have a set X including n elements. I want to find out m subsets of X with the same size. Given a constant k, every element of X occurs exactly in the k subsets. And the size of intersection between any two (three, four,...,k) subsets is constant such as |S1∩S2|=|S1∩S3|=c2,|S1∩S2∩S5|=|S1∩S3∩S4|=c3..., but c2 doesn't need to equal c3. How to solve it?

Comment: This is really unclear.  "every element of X occurs exactly in the k subsets" -- do you mean "every element of X occurs in exactly **one of** the k subsets?"  And which k subsets?  Did you mean "m" instead of "k"?

Comment: What if the input? Is it "*n, m, k*"? Is it *X*? (*X* doesn't seem important, only *n* is...)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks for your comments. "every element of X occurs exactly in the k subsets" means that for any element x of X, in the m subsets only k subsets contain x. For example, X={a,b,c,d,e,f}, m=3, k=2, then the  subsets may be  "{a,b,c,d}, {c,d,e,f}, {e,f,a,b}".

Comment: @Amit Yes. The input is n, m, k.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that: m>=k && (n*k)%m=0 && that a solution exists?

Comment: @Amit I don't know if there's other constraint to guarantee it has solution. But at least it needs to meet the condition you gave.

Comment: There are other constraints that I can't quite define right now (it takes more time to analyze and prove) but for example *n=6 m=6 k=6* had no solution (feel free to try). It is my belief that the set of valid combination of parameters is "very small" (it might be infinite, but most random combinations, even those that satisfy the basic rules set before won't work), and perhaps it's even limited to a few special cases. What is the origin of this problem?

Comment: @Amit Actually this question comes from a problem in my work. This is the problem: I have a list of documents (X). I need to find out m groups of documents from the list and give them to m persons to read, which need to meet the condition that every document is read by 2 (here k is 2) people, and any two persons have the same number of overlapping documents.  So in my task, usually n is much larger than m, and n is usually 2 or 3 (less than 4).

Comment: Based on your last comment, it's starting to sound like you might be looking for something called a combinatorial design.  I suggest googling that.